# how to pass parameters on reload of datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable that I initialize like this:

```
mytable = DataTable({
        ajax:{
            url: "/url/getTableData",
            dataSrc: ""

        },
        sortClasses: false,
        paging: false,
        scrollY: 300,
        columns: cols
    });
```

later I'd like to do

```
mytable.ajax.reload();
```

It works fine, but now I'd like to send a few parameters in that request. Those parameters I only need on reload, and not in the initialization of the table.
How do I do that?
thank you!

Comment: Did you read the documentation at all? It looks like you can use either of these right before you reload: http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url() and http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Comment: I did read the documentation, but I was not able to find the answer. I did not want to change the url, only the params. And I'm not sure if using the url like you suggested helps me in that sense, although it is, indeed, a solution.

Comment: Depending on what you meant by "a few parameters", changing the URL was an option (adding a querystring). But if you wanted to pass data in the body of a POST request, then use my second link (http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) - I'm pretty sure that's a much better example than the answer you accepted, and it seems to be for exactly what you're trying to do, not a hacky solution to it

Comment: it looks like the right answer. I'll try that. Thank you so much for explaining that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Option 1** - Use the preXhr.dt event.

```
table = $('#example')
    .on('preXhr.dt', function ( e, settings, data ) {
        data.whateveryouwant = $("#someidhere").val()
        data.anotherexample = "kittens"
    } )
// then just setup your datatable as normal
    .DataTable({
        ajax:{
            url: "/url/getTableData",
            type: "GET" // This is the default value, could also be POST
        },
        sortClasses: false,
        paging: false,
        scrollY: 300,
        columns: cols
});
```

see here http://datatables.net/reference/event/

**Option 2 (preferred)** - Use an ajax.data function.

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax:{
        url: "/url/getTableData", // Change this URL to where your json data comes from
        type: "GET", // This is the default value, could also be POST, or anything you want.
        data: function(d) {
            d.whateveryouwant = $("#someidhere").val()
            d.anotherexample = "kittens"
        }

    },
    sortClasses: false,
    paging: false,
    scrollY: 300,
    columns: cols
});
```

Both options produce identical results. Your server will not know the difference. The extra data will be added on every `table.ajax.reload()`. The extra data will be:

`whateveryouwant` of with value of the `#someidhere` element, and

`anotherexample` with the value `"kittens"`

I prefer the **Option 2**, because it's more obvious that extra data is being added on each request. The first option is a little bit sneaky and not as obvious for someone else reading your code I think.

Comment: Thank you for outstanding answer (+1). 

Short question: Why is not working {data: "whatEverYouWant" :  $("#someidhere").val() ) beacuse it' sn ot working but with function is working? 

I'm newbie in javascript

Answer (score 0):

My use case is different in that I don't want to permanently change the ajax action for the page.  This works for me to change the ajax calls only when refresh is clicked, meaning serverside calls (ie for table sorting etc) can have a different behavior:

```
    // Create a refresh button
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.refresh = {
        text: 'Refresh',
        action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
          var origurl = dt.ajax.url();
          dt.ajax.url(origurl+"?forcereload=true").load();
          dt.ajax.url(origurl);
        }
    };
```