# Datatables 1.10 and ajax.reload() with new data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to upgrade from older Datatables to the new Datatables 1.10.
The problem is that I use a form to create custom filters and would like to for example each time a select changes, the table reloads with the new data filtered.

here is part of the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#main_table_<?=MODULO?>_<?=THIS?>').DataTable({
            dom         : 'T<"clearfix">lfrt<"clearfix">ip',
            stateSave   : true,
            pageLength  : 25,
            pagingType  : "full_numbers",
            processing  : true,
            serverSide  : true,

            ajax        : {
                        url : "<?=CAMINHO?>_lista_registos_busca.php",
                        data: buildSearchData
            }

        });

        function buildSearchData(){
            var obj = {
                id_utilizador       : $("select#id_utilizador option:selected").val(),
                id_departamento     : $("select#id_departamento option:selected").val(),
                id_escritorio       : $("select#id_escritorio option:selected").val(),
                id_contrato_tipo    : $("select#id_contrato_tipo option:selected").val(),
            };
            return obj;
        }

        $("select#id_utilizador, select#id_departamento, select#id_escritorio, select#id_contrato_tipo").change(function () {
            table.ajax.reload();
        });
```

ajax.reload() works great and data is properly sent, except that none of the Datatable parameters is sent. The alternative method:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#main_table_<?=MODULO?>_<?=THIS?>').DataTable({
            dom         : 'T<"clearfix">lfrt<"clearfix">ip',
            stateSave   : true,
            pageLength  : 25,
            pagingType  : "full_numbers",
            processing  : true,
            serverSide  : true,

            ajax        : {
                        url : "<?=CAMINHO?>_lista_registos_busca.php",
                        data: {
                           id_utilizador    : $("select#id_utilizador option:selected").val(),
                           id_departamento  : $("select#id_departamento option:selected").val(),
                           id_escritorio    : $("select#id_escritorio option:selected").val(),
                           id_contrato_tipo : $("select#id_contrato_tipo option:selected").val(),

                       }

            }

        });
```

Like this, all data is sent, ajax.reload() reloads the table but the data from the selects is not updated on change.

Any one of you guys can help me in solving this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rolling back to 1.9 ... can't find a sollution for this anywhere. Can't believe anyone ever used this for more complex data filtering. In 1.9 I can do it easy with fnServerData and aoData.push... in 1.10, can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed `()` so that the `buildSeachData` function is actually not called.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#main_table_<?=MODULO?>_<?=THIS?>').DataTable({
        dom         : 'T<"clearfix">lfrt<"clearfix">ip',
        stateSave   : true,
        pageLength  : 25,
        pagingType  : "full_numbers",
        processing  : true,
        serverSide  : true,

        ajax        : {
                    url : "<?=CAMINHO?>_lista_registos_busca.php",
                    data: buildSearchData()
        }

    });

    function buildSearchData(){
        var obj = {
            id_utilizador       : $("select#id_utilizador option:selected").val(),
            id_departamento     : $("select#id_departamento option:selected").val(),
            id_escritorio       : $("select#id_escritorio option:selected").val(),
            id_contrato_tipo    : $("select#id_contrato_tipo option:selected").val(),
        };
        return obj;
    }

    $("select#id_utilizador, select#id_departamento, select#id_escritorio, select#id_contrato_tipo").change(function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    });
```

Comment: Hello, adding the missing (), it does pass the all Datatable parameters and form parameters, but does not re-send new data with the trigger change and subsequently the table.ajax.reload().

Answer (score 0):

Is the way you are binding your `data` to `ajax.data`.

Instead of:

```
ajax: {
       url : "<?=CAMINHO?>_lista_registos_busca.php",
       data: buildSearchData
}
```

Try this:

```
ajax: {
       url : "<?=CAMINHO?>_lista_registos_busca.php",
       data: function (d) {
                Object.assign(d, buildSearchData);
                return d;
            }
}
```

This way you 'intercept' DataTables post parameters and you merge your own parameters.

For documentation:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

For other stackoverflow related issues:

[how to pass parameters on reload of datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499116/how-to-pass-parameters-on-reload-of-datatables?rq=1)

[DataTables ajax.reload() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412845/datatables-ajax-reload-with-parametes)

Hope it helped!