# DataTables ajax.reload() with parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, typescript, datatables

I am using DataTables **serverSide** in an Angular2 project.

I am trying to reload the table after making changes, and those changes I want to pass them as parameters in POST via AJAX.

The thing is that DataTables is always getting  the `options` object from the initialization, and not an updated version with the **new parameters**.

So, **what I need** is, to use `ajax.reload()` passing a new set of parameters.

This is my current function:

```
filterData(tableParams) {
    console.log('reloading DT. tableparams received are: ' + JSON.stringify(tableParams));

    let element = $(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]);
    let table = element.find('table.dataTable');
    table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
}
```

At the moment, as you can see, I'm not using `tableParams`, this is because I wanted to show a clean version of my function, I tried many things and none of them worked.

**DataTables always gets the initial `options` object**, with the initial parameters.

This is one of my desperate attempts:

```
filterData(tableParams) {
    let element = $(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]);
    let table = element.find('table.dataTable');
    table.DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: this.jsonApiService.buildURL('/test_getUsers.php'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: tableParams,
        },
    }).ajax.reload();
}
```

Some help would be much appreciated. If you need further explanations on how the DataTable is created, or more code snippets let me know. But I think that the issue is just with the `ajax.reload()` function, being able to send updated parameters will solve the issue.

Thanks very much!

**Edit 1**

This is my init `options` object:

```
            let data = {
                email: true,
                test: 'init',
            };

            this.options = {
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                pageLength: 20,
                searchDelay: 1200,
                ajax: {
                    url: this.jsonApiService.buildURL('/test_getUsers.php'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'userId'},
                    {data: 'userCode'},
                    {data: 'userName'},
                    {data: 'userRole'},
                    {data: 'userEmail'},
                ],
            };
```

And these are the parameters that DataTables is sending:

[image]

*(Among other DataTables parameters)*

When I call `ajax.reload()`, no matter the things I have tried, I end up sending these same parameters, therefore, sending the init parameters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally got the solution, the problem was that I was too focused on achieving my goal through `DataTable().ajax.reload()`. I wanted to pass the parameters through there in one way or another, and that was incorrect.

I had to change the construction of the `options` object.
As you saw earlier, I was assigning **my custom parameters** to the `options` object like this:

```
ajax: {
  url: this.jsonApiService.buildURL('/test_getUsers.php'),
  type: 'POST',
  data: this.params,
}
```

Where `data: this.params` would get the data from somewhere, in my case, I had 2 listeners, one for *init* and another for *updating* that change `this.params` value. This, instead of a listener could be an `onChange()`, but **the point is that the parameters change at runtime**.

So I simply had to put this into a function, and merge DataTable's parameters to my own parameters.

**This is my solution:**

```
data: function (d) {
    Object.assign(d, myClass.params);
    return d;
}
```

With this `options` object, when I have to refresh the DataTable sending new parameters to the server, I simply call `ajax.reload()`. DataTables will get the `options` object with the latest `data` and reload itself.

I really hope this can help someone! Good work and happy coding!

Answer (score 13):

**In some cases you may want to change ajax url at runtime or apply any additional query parameters.**

So you can do like this:

```
var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({...});    
dataTable.ajax.url('/new-ajax-url?someParam=1').load();
```

**It works with version v1.10.16 of the library.**

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": function (d) {
        d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
    }
  }
});
```

then simply call:

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to send new parameters with each request and not have to destroy and rebuild the datatable every time as well. I heavily use datatables on my site and was wanting an easier method for handling my use case so I came up with this. Maybe it will be useful for someone else.

**buildDT.js :**

```
        ;(function (){ 
        
    'use strict';
    
    /**
     * dtReload is used for setting new param 
     * to send to the server with out having 
     * to reload the table
     */
    var dtReload = {};
    /**
     * This is the object containing
     * the param to be sent to the server 
     */
    dtReload.param = {};
    /**
     * Adds the param to the object used by datatables
     * for the request
     * @param param object datatables object
     * @param extra object extra params to send to the server
     * @return object
     */
    dtReload.proccParam = (param, extra) => {
      $.each(extra, function(i,e){
        param[i] = e;
      })
      return param;
    }
    
    class buildDataTable {
        
        #url = '';
        #method = 'POST';
        
        #dtOptions = {};
        #responsive = true;
        #pageLength = 10;
        #lengthMenu = [5, 10, 20];
        #processing = true;
        #serverSide = true;
        #language = {}; 
        #initComplete;
        #columns = [];
        #columnDefs = [];

        ajaxParam;
        
        constructor(){}
        
        setURL(url){
            this.#url = url
        }
        
        setPageLength(pageLengthInt){
            if(pageLengthInt == 'undeinfed'){
              this.#pageLength = 10;
            }else if(typeof pageLengthInt == "number"){
              this.#pageLength = pageLengthInt;
            }else{
              console.log('Colums should be of type Array');
            }
        }
        
        setColumns(columnsArray){
            if(columnsArray == 'undefined'){
              this.#columns = [];
            }else if(typeof columnsArray == "object" && true == Array.isArray(columnsArray)){
              this.#columns = columnsArray;
            }else{
              console.log('Colums should be of type Array');
            }
        }
        
        setColumnDefs(columnDefsArray){
            if(language == 'undefined'){    
                this.#columnDefs = [
                  { targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false }
                ]   
            }else if(typeof columnDefsArray == "object" && true == Array.isArray(columnDefsArray)){
                this.#columnDefs = columnDefsArray;
            }else{
                console.log('Coulmn Definitions should be of type Array');
            }
        }
        
        setLanguage(language){
            if(language == 'undefined'){
              this.#language = {
                infoEmpty: "No Data To Display",
                emptyTable: "No Data To Display",
                zeroRecords: "No Data To Display"
              }
            }else if(typeof language == "object" && false == Array.isArray(language)){
                this.#language = language;
            }else{
                console.log('Language should be of type object');
            }
        }
        
        setInitComplete(func){              
            this.#initComplete = function(settings, json){
                if(typeof func == "function"){
                  func(settings,json);
                }
            }
        }
        
        setParam(param){ 
          this.ajaxParam = param;
        }
        
        getParam(){     
            return this.ajaxParam;
        }
        
        makeAjax(param){
          dtReload.param = param;
          return {
            url:this.#url,
            dataSrc:'data.result',
            data:function(d){   
              dtReload.proccParam(d, dtReload.param)
            },
            method:this.#method
          }
        }   
        
        #setOptions(){      
            this.#dtOptions = {         
                responsive:this.#responsive,
                pageLength:this.#pageLength,
                lengthMenu:this.#lengthMenu,
                processing:this.#processing,
                serverSide:this.#serverSide,
                language:this.#language,
                ajax:this.makeAjax(this.getParam()),
                initComplete:this.#initComplete,
                columns:this.#columns,
                columnDef:this.#columnDefs          
            }   
        }
        
        getOptions(){
          this.#setOptions();
          return this.#dtOptions;
        }   
    }
    
    window.dtReload = dtReload;
    window.buildDataTable = buildDataTable;
    
    
    })();
```

**Useage**

```
    var builder = new buildDataTable();
    var myDTableObject;
    
    function doSomething(id){
    
      // Pass the param 
      builder.setParam({
         someParam : 'doSomething',
         id:id,
         token : token_value
      });
    
      // Set the server url
      builder.setURL('http://your/url')
      // Setup your columns
      builder.setColumns([
        { "data": function(data){return columnProcess(data).id} },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": function(data){return columnProcess(data).status} },
        { "data": "date" },
        { "data": "options" }   
      ])
      
      // Check if datatables is loaded and setup
      if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#yourTable')){
          // Set the new param
          dtReload.param = builder.getParam();
          // Reload the table
          myDTableObject.ajax.reload();
      }else{
        // Init table setup
        myDTableObject = $('#yourTable').DataTable(
          builder.getOptions()
        );
      } 
    }
```

Thanks to [@sraxi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385459/sraxi) for the idea of using the function in the ajax request to process the param.

I created a GitHub Repo for this here: [DataTableReload](https://github.com/snowballrandom/DataTableReload/)