# DataTables reload table with different pageLength param

Tags: pagination, datatables

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499116/how-to-pass-parameters-on-reload-of-datatables) question.

I initialize my [datatables.js](https://www.datatables.net) table with the following code:

```js
 var table_entity = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "pageLength":getParameterByName('pageLength'),//getting param from query string
    fixedHeader: true,
     "ajax": {
         "url": myUrl,
          "data": function(d) {
                d.type = $('#mytype').val();
            }
     }
});
```

So I know how to reload my datatable with different ajax params. Now I need to reload it with different `pageLength` param which does not belong to ajax section and is recorded during datatables `init` stage. I tried to pass it directly during reloading with the following code:

```js
table_entity.ajax.reload({
    "pageLength":77 //some new param different from the initial one
});
```

But it did not work, the table is reloaded with initial `pageLength` value. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

**UPD_1**

managed to do that with

1st: complete destruction of a table:

```js
$('#MyTable').DataTable().destroy();
$('#MyTable tbody').empty();//note tbody here
```

2nd: reinit the table with updated params:

```js
table_data.displayStart   = Number(getParameterByName('displayStart'));
table_data.pageLength     = Number(getParameterByName('pageLength'));
table_data.iDisplayStart  = Number(getParameterByName('displayStart'));
table_data.iDisplayLength = Number(getParameterByName('pageLength'));

$('#MyTable').DataTable(table_data);
```

Note 2 params - `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength` here

Is it possible to do the same without destruction of the table, but during `ajax.reload` phase? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the same without destruction of the table, but
>   during ajax.reload phase?

You can hook into the [**`xhr.dt`**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event and update [**`page.len()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()) from there. Example :

```js
$('#example').on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, json, xhr) {
  table.page.len(json.data.length).draw()
})
```

Will dynamically set the page length to maximum i.e length of `data`. Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d72zbyus/**

So you could use `table.page.len(77).draw()` or whatever. `xhr.dt` is triggered after each AJAX request.

It is not clear to me where your new `pageLength` come from exactly. If it is part of the returned JSON (as I suspect) you could do `table.page.len(json.pageLength).draw()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, is it possible to update page start parameter in the same way as pageLength?

Comment: @Jack, you can the same way use `table.page( json.displayStart ).draw( 'page' )` see https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()